# is there any solution to do API rejection in WooComerce Distance rate shipping?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, woocommerce, shipping-method

I've followed the instructions provided by the WooCommerce Distance Rate Shipping documentation to enable the Google Distance Matrix API and Google Maps Embed API. Despite following the steps precisely, I'm encountering the error message:

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. This API key is not authorized to use this service or API.

Here's a breakdown of the steps I've taken:

1. Created credentials and selected API key.
2. Chose "Restrict Key" and ensured that restrictions were set to "None" and "Don't restrict key."
3. Saved the settings.

Despite completing these steps, I'm still facing the authorization error. I've attached screenshots of my configuration for reference.

###### Error Msg show in WooCommerce backend:

[image]

###### Both APIs enabled:

[image]

###### Error message encountered in the cart page:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h21HP.png]

I'm attempting to activate the distance rate shipping plugin on my website, but upon doing so, I encountered the error message: 'Google Maps Platform rejected your request. This API key is not authorized to use this service or API.'

My expectation was that by following the provided instructions, enabling the Google Distance Matrix API, and the Google Maps Embed API, I would successfully integrate the shipping method into my website. However, I'm unable to proceed due to this authorization issue. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Try re-enabling the APIs, try generating a new key. Try using the various APIs with your key outside the plugin. Depending on your findings, contact Google or refer to the plugin developers.